# Having a hard time tracking down a process that is crashing my app pool

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, event-viewer

So I have an app that keeps crashing out and it's not leaving any application logs. When I finally went and looked in the event viewer for that server (a server 2003 box), I found this error (The even source was ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0)

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2053196604/Root
>
> Process ID: 24428
>
> Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException
>
> Message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.505.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> StackTrace:  Server stack trace:     at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName,
>   ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.Unity.UnityContainerConfigurator.AddValidationExtension()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.Unity.UnityContainerConfigurator..ctor(IUnityContainer
>   container)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(IConfigurationSource
>   configurationSource)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.SetCurrentContainerIfNotSet()
>   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.get_Writer()
>   at Apriva.WebApi.Shared.Logging.DefaultLogWriter.Log(Object message,
>   TraceEventType severity, LogEntry& entry, String category, HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Apriva.WebApi.Shared.Logging.DefaultLogWriter.Info(Object message,
>   String category, HttpContext context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message
>   reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed,
>   MessageData& msgData)    at
>   Apriva.WebApi.Shared.Logging.Logger.LogDelegate.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Apriva.WebApi.Shared.Logging.Logger.LogAsyncComplete(IAsyncResult ar) 
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.DoAsyncCall()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object
>   o)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at

When I check the processes in the task manager, this PID isn't present. I figure it's because it is a w3wp process. So I go to command prompt and run iisapp.vbs and it returns a single process with a different PID.

The error seems to imply that there is a config reference to a different version of the enterprise library for validation when the version that was found was v5.0.505.0 and while my projects have plenty of references to the enterprise library, none refer to the validation package.

So my question is -- does anyone have any insight into where I should look next? I was trying to use the PID to at least see which application was causing the error, but that doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis:**
From stack trace its clear that reference chain is:
Apriva.WebApi.Shared.Logging.DefaultLogWriter => Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger => Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer => Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.Unity.UnityContainerConfigurator.
Method "AddValidationExtension" of type Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.Unity.UnityContainerConfigurator needs type from 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation assembly with signature

**Possible steps find out root cause:**

1. Open solution in visual studio.
2. Go to Edit Menu-> Find and Replace->Find in Files
3. Search for Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation with Find options->Look at these file types -> *.csproj You will get list of project referencing this assembly.
4. Open all those project files in notepad and find out which one has different assembly signature than Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Most probably you should get culprit with above steps.
I will also recommend to check assembly cache and check signature of Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation assembly and if it matches Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'